# How to run a function in every page in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, cookies, module, angularjs

I have created a function that validates if a Cookie exists and I want to run this function in every page using angularjs. I just can't seem to make the function run. Should I put it the module on in a new controller?

This is how far I reached:

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/products', {templateUrl: '/tmpl/products.html', controller: Ctrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'})
  }]).run( function($rootScope, $location) {

 //should I call it here?
 //validateCookie();


});

function validateCookie($scope, $cookieStore, $http){


}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think there would be a couple ways of solving this. If you want to cause this validation to happen every time you change routes (which means it will run when the application first starts as well as on every page that you go to within the application), you could do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/index', {templateUrl: '/tmpl/index.html', controller: IndexCtrl}).
        when('/products', {templateUrl: '/tmpl/products.html', controller: Ctrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'})
}])
.run(function($rootScope, validateCookie) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        validateCookie($rootScope);
    })
})
.factory('validateCookie', function($cookieStore, $http){
    return function(scope) {
        // Validate the cookie here...
    }
})
```

If you don't need to run on every route change, you could just change the "run" function:

```
.run(function($rootScope, validateCookie) {
    validateCookie($rootScope);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can tie into the route events (routeChangeStart) to test this before the route changes? If test fails, redirect.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route

Discussion on canceling a route change:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/-yPBLMJQO_Q

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a service that you will want to inject into your controllers. The angular site has a good example of how to do this: [Creating Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services). Normally if you want to use some logic in many places creating a service is the way to do it.

Comment: The next part of the dev guide is about injecting a service into a controller http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers. That would be good to read as well

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate combining the **routeProvider resolve** property and using **Services**.

**Overview video**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr1qZ8Ik9G8

**API Details**

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider